# Set parameter for url

Tags: symfony, url, parameters, routes

My reset password requires a parameter/ token to identify the user in order to reset the password.

My approach is to generate a url with a token (eg: `test.site.com/resetpassword/sample_token`) inorder to validate the user and allow him/ her to reset password.

**Problem :** is that when I setup the `routing.yml` to accept parameters, and navigate to the url (`test.site.com/resetpassword`) it will produce a `The server returned a "404 Not Found".` error which I presume is acceptable and if I set a parameter like so `test.site.com/resetpassword/test` it would redirect to the default page which is the sign in page. But to my requirement it should open up the reset password form.

I tried the methods described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#adding-requirements but was of no use and produced similar failed attempts as described in the problem.

My `routing.yml` implementation is as follows,

```
test_accounts_homepage:
  path:     /
  defaults: { _controller: TestAccountsBundle:Index:index }

test_accounts_login:
  path:     /signin
  defaults: { _controller: TestAccountsBundle:Signin:index }    

test_accounts_resetpassword:
  path:     /resetpassword/{userToken}
  defaults: { _controller: TestAccountsBundle:ResetPassword:index }
  requirements:
    userToken: ".+"
    _method: GET
```

**FYI :** I tried the code in debugging mode and it did not even reach the controller.

Any help on this matter would be of great help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with following changes

1. Update `userToken:"[a-z0-9-_]+"`
2. Check *ResetPassword* controller if it requires login for password reset page.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. but this also resulted in the same error..do I need to make any changes within config files?

Comment: Check ResetPassword controller once. It might have been set requiring login for password reset page.

Comment: That was exactly the issue..but changing the `access_control` settings in `security.yml` file. Your suggestion lead me to this answer.. can you please update the answer so I could mark it as answered.